# Include all javascript files from application except a specific folder in Rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to exclude a specific folder from `assets/javascripts` in my `application.html.haml`

The folder that I do not want to be included in my layout is `mobile` folder

Here's my layout:

```
%html(lang="en")
  %head
    %meta(charset="utf-8")
    %meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1")
    %meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    %title= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : @user.name ? 'Niche | ' + @user.name : 'Niche'
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = analytics_init if Rails.env.production?
    / Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements
    /[if lt IE 9]
      = javascript_include_tag "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.1/html5shiv.js"
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"

  %body#profile

    %section.persist-area
      %header.global.profile
        %div.container
          %a.brand.pull-left{ :href => root_path }
            .logo-niche


          %nav.pull-right
            = render 'layouts/menu'

      .container-fluid#main
        = yield :profile

      /
        Javascripts
        \==================================================
      / Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster
      = javascript_include_tag "application"
      = yield :javascript
```

In this snippet, I am getting all JS:

```
= javascript_include_tag "application"
```

But I want to get all JS except the folder named `mobile`

I tried the following workaround but did not work:

```
= javascript_include_tag "application", except: "mobile"
```

Sorry that was just a wild guess. There's no `javascript_exclude_tag` too as per the docs.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**PS:** I have a different layout for mobile, so that's why I really want to exclude that folder in desktop view. It's conflicting a lot of conflicts in my desktop view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in application.js

```
//= require_tree
```

to

```
//= require_directory .
```

or

```
//= require_tree ./useful
```

So that, app/assets/javascripts/* files will be included and app/assets/javascripts/mobile/* wont be included.

Comment: So then... other folders will not be required (e.g. I also have a lib folder)? Is there any way to exclude just one folder? Thanks btw for the reply.

Comment: I would do "//= require_tree ./useful" and under useful, all folders and files that I require will be kept. "/mobile" will be excluded. Here I assume 2 folders in my "app/assets/javascripts", "mobile and useful"

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I used `stub` as well. Just for additional info, if others encounter this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602393/rails-3-1-sprockets-require-directives-is-there-a-way-to-exclude-particular-fi