# Rails + Backbone - exclude directory in assets require_tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, assets

I develop a backbone application integrated with Rails.
My backbone application is under `app/assets/javascripts/src`, however I want to include it only in the **admin** namespace.

The problem is the last line of `application.js` include all javascript assets:

```
//= require_tree .
```

I would like to exclude the `src` directory. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by writing a new manifest file and including it in all your admin pages. For example you can create an `admin.js` manifest file. Then make sure Rails compiles it by adding this to your `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js']
```

And then include it in your html files that are in the admin namespace with:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "admin" %>
```

Make sure to not put `require_tree` within the `admin.js` file but rather only include files that are necessary for the admin namespace.

---

Documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

Comment: Can you please refer me to the documentation? Would like to read more about it.

Comment: Updated with documentation link

Comment: This is great but not enough. What I don't understand is how to prevent rails include all files under assets/javascripts. One thing is to create a manifest file in order to include the application where I need it, other thing is to avoid it to be included in all pages of the project.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611240/835696 it's possible if you have the right version of sprockets. Otherwise you're kind of out of luck

Comment: This is a nice one, thanks! It works for me, however it has one problem - looks like `stub` works with __files__ but not with __directories__... nothing is perfect :-(